# Each Function to Select Current page in Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll, pushstate

I've put in a little bit of Jquery into a site that loads and appends the next page when you get near the bottom of the current page. I want to detect where the user is on the page so that I can modify the URL with history.pushstate().

Each page is wrapped in the 'load-part' class.

```
var load_number;
var start_offset;
var end_offset;
// Run a function on each page
$('.load-part').each(function() {

    // Get the page number 
    load_number = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace("load-part-",""));

    // Get the true top offset of the page
    start_offset = $(this).children().first().offset().top;

    // Get the true bottom offset of the page
    end_offset = $(this).children().last().offset().top + window_height;

    // If the window is between the limits - i.e. on this page
    if (start_offset <= $(window).scrollTop() < end_offset) {

        // Update the URL with the current page number
        history.pushState(null, null, load_number)
    }
});
```

The problem I'm getting is that the if statement seems to be evaluating true regardless, even when the window.scrollTop() value clearly doesn't fall between the limits. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (start_offset <= $(window).scrollTop() && $(window).scrollTop() < end_offset) {

        // Update the URL with the current page number
        history.pushState(null, null, load_number)
    }
```

Is something more javascript-enabled

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks. I'm not entirely sure why you have to split up if conditions like this?

Comment: Because i'm sorry to say that: it's how conditionals are working in js, one test at a time.